# How do i render a .svelte component inside a +server.ts file in SvelteKit

Tags: tailwind-css, rendering, svelte, server-side-rendering, sveltekit

I am trying to render a svelte component from within the route/api/report/+server.ts route. The idea is to create an HTML string with the component including CSS.

I am using TailWind css.

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot. You see a `+server.ts` file is a server-only file. It's purpose is to run API-like functions that you can call from your client code. In order to render components you will need to use a `+page.svelte` file. On the firs call, the `+page.svelte` "renders" the components in the server. Maybe, try to explain what and why you are trying to accomplish and see if somebody can give you some workarounds.